# Create a new column based on transposed data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame with 5 columns of type float64, each column got the amount spent on each of them. 
And I would like to have only two columns (AMount Spent and Source). I have tried to transpose the data but it didn't work as I only get as rows the amount of columns I had in the original dataset

Is there any way I can do it?

To clarify I have a Data frame like this:

[image: 1Original Data Frame]

And I would like to get this:

[image: Final df]

Greetings and thanks in advance,

Andrés

Comment: `df.melt(value_name='Amount', var_name='Source')`?

Comment: Or `df.stack().reset_index(level=0,drop=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `pivot = df.pivot_table(index = "Amount",values = "Source")`